# Слайдер на js(с меняющимся задним фоном у элементов)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Суть идеи такова, что при изменении слайда, меняется и задний фон предыдущего и следующего слайда, пример видно на картинке: К примеру при нажатии на блок B его задний фон переходит в блок А, в тоже время задний фон с блока А переходить в блок С[image: Слайдер] Жду ваших предложений по реализации ! Заранее спасибо!

Вот html :

```
           <div class="works__slider">
           <div class="slider__photo-current">
               <img style="max-width: 90%;" src="img/content/slider-current.png" alt="slider current" class="current__photo">
           </div>
           <div class="slider__photo__else">
               <div class="photo__else-prev">
                    <svg class="header__social-svg socials__git-svg">
                        <use xlink:href="img/icons/sprite.svg#arrow-down"></use>
                    </svg>
               </div>
               <div class="photo__else-next">
                    <svg class="header__social-svg socials__git-svg">
                        <use xlink:href="img/icons/sprite.svg#arrow-up"></use>
                    </svg>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

А вот scss:

```
    .works__slider {
        width: 50%; // Не стоит обращать внимания, так нужно по макету

        .slider__photo-current {
            height: 75%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #efebe0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;

        }

        .slider__photo__else {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            height: 25%;

            .photo__else-prev {
                width: 50%;
                background: url(../img/content/web-down.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;

            }

            .photo__else-next {
                width: 50%;
                background: url(../img/content/web-up.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А с чем именно у вас проблемы возникли? Есть какие-то наработки?

Comment: На данный момент есть только верстка, думаю над реализацией на js

Comment: ну так добавьте в вопрос верстку, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода..."

Comment: Я добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что вам нужно?

> [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/cpqux9k8/)

```
window.currPhoto=0;//номер текущего фото
window.onload=sliding('right');//запуск слайдера

function sliding(side){
    var photoArr=[],
photoDiv=document.querySelectorAll('#slider #photo img'),//указатель на блок с фото
leftBtn=document.querySelector('.left'),//на левую кнопку
rightBtn=document.querySelector('.right');//на правую
    switch(side){
        case "right":
        if(photoDiv[currPhoto])photoDiv[currPhoto].style.display="none";
        leftBtn.style.background="url("+photoDiv[currPhoto].getAttribute('src')+")";
        rightBtn.style.background="url("+photoDiv[currPhoto+(currPhoto!==photoDiv.length-2&&currPhoto!==photoDiv.length-1?2:0-photoDiv.length+2)].getAttribute('src')+")";
        currPhoto+=currPhoto!==photoDiv.length-1?1:0-photoDiv.length+1;
        break;
        case "left":
        photoDiv[currPhoto].style.display="none";
        rightBtn.style.background="url("+photoDiv[currPhoto].getAttribute('src')+")";
        leftBtn.style.background="url("+photoDiv[currPhoto-(currPhoto===1||currPhoto===0?0-photoDiv.length+2:2)].getAttribute('src')+")";
        currPhoto-=currPhoto===0?0-photoDiv.length+1:1;
        break;
    }
    photoDiv[currPhoto].style.display="block";
}
```